# PHP Sessions Exist on log in but not on another page

Tags: php, session

So I have a login script that calls a custom user class, the user logs in and a session gets set. Doing a var dump on the redict to the login.php page confirms that the user has sucessfully logged in and a friendly welcome message is displayed.

The code to set the session is:

```
private function setIsLoggedIn($credentials) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }
    $_SESSION['verified'] = $credentials;
    session_write_close();
}
```

Which is working fine for the login.php page, the arguments to the function are:

```
// assign user info from db to the session
        $this->setIsLoggedIn(array('UserId' => $user->userid,
            'UserName' => $user->username,
            'RoleId' => $user->roleid));
```

this is the login.php form post back

```
// if the form was submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

// Set local variables from $_POST array elements (userlogin and userpassword) or empty strings
    $userLogin = (isset($_POST['userlogin'])) ? trim($_POST['userlogin']) : '';
    $userPassword = (isset($_POST['userpassword'])) ? trim($_POST['userpassword']) : '';

    //assign values to array and get user object
    $authArray = array('UserName' => $userLogin, 'Password' => $userPassword);
    $user = new Users($authArray);

    if ($user->getUserId() > 0) { //If credentials check out

        // redirect the user to SESSION value set from common class
        if (isset($_SESSION['prev_page']))
        {
            header('location:' . $_SESSION['prev_page'] );
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise, assign error message to $msg
            $msg = '<p><strong>Thank your for logging in.<br  />You may now visit tools that are in development.</strong></p>';
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Otherwise, assign error message to $msg
        $msg = '<p><strong>Sorry, that username and password are not recognized.<br  />Please try again.</strong></p>';
    }
}
```

Now I get to another page and do a $var_dump($_SESSION); I always get something else, because in the page I'm setting this:

```
$_SESSION['prev_page'] = "http://".$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]."/id/AphID/";
```

the first lines of this file are:

```
<?php
session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Here are my PHP session settings:

```
Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   On  On
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length  16  16
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    user    files
session.save_path   /tmp    /tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   1   1
```

So,  basically my session only truly exists on the login page and no where else, and when I call Session_start(); I always get a different session. Any ideas?

Comment: Where set you $_SESSION['prev_page']? If it's set after session_write_close call, it has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session_write_close() ends the session after saving the data. The next call to session_start() will create a new session.

If you want to restore the session after closing it then before you close it you need to save the session id somewhere. `$sid = session_id()` You could save it in a database or cookie.

Then to restore the session you could call `session_id($sid); session_start();`

Comment: how do I re-open this session?